# What is a pullback in simple calculus context?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

The definition of a pullback provided by my text is quite accessible

> Let $\phi : M \to N$, $f:N \to \mathbb{R}$, then $f\circ \phi: M \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\phi^*f = f\circ\phi$ and $\phi^*$ is the pullback of
>   $f$ by $\phi$

But when I look up some examples, things like category theory and sheafs and differential forms pop up!

I only have a background in calculus, can someone provide a simple examples from calculus to illustrate the idea of a pullback? and why is pullback problematic/pathological/not desired??

Comment: Simply let $M=N=\mathbb{R}$ and let $f$, $\phi$ be nice functions of your choosing. It should be easy to construct. :)

Comment: The pullback should be defined to act on vector fields I think.

Comment: What is "your text" ?

Comment: @RogelioMolina Vector fields are pushed forward by the differential. Forms eat pushed-forward things, so they are pulled back.

Comment: @Neal Indeed, thanks for the correction, I always mix up these two!

Comment: (I would add that for Riemannian manifolds, there is a canonical identification between vector fields and forms, so they can be mixed up there.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The chain rule and its attendant method of substitution in calculus are the most elementary "useful" example that comes to mind. Let $M = [\alpha, \beta]$ and $N = [a, b]$ be compact $1$-manifolds with boundary...er...I mean, closed, bounded intervals.

- If $\phi:M \to N$ is a differentiable map (a.k.a. function) and $f:N \to \mathbf{R}$ is differentiable, then the pullback of the $0$-form $f$ on $N$ is the $0$-form $\phi^{*}f = f \circ \phi$ on $M$, and
  $$
  d(\phi^{*}f) = f'\bigl(\phi(x)\bigr)\phi'(x)\, dx = \phi^{*}(df).
  $$
- If $\phi:M \to N$ is an increasing, continuously-differentiable bijection, and $f:N \to \mathbf{R}$ is a continuous function, then the change of variables formula
  $$
  \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\, dx
    = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f\bigl(\phi(t)\bigr)\, \phi'(t)\, dt
  $$
  asserts the fact that if $\omega = f(x)\, dx$, then
  $$
  \int_{N} \omega = \int_{M} \phi^{*}\omega.
  $$

The change of variables theorem in multivariable calculus is a higher-dimensional, slightly less-elementary example of a pullback, used every time you convert a Cartesian integral to polar (or cylindrical, or spherical...) coordinates, or integrate a function or a vector field over a curve or surface.

Comment: Just to clarify because my brain is small: 1. a 1-manifold is an open interval? 2. diffeomorphism on a 1-manifold is equivalent to a one variable differentiable function? 3. what do you mean by 0-form $f$ on N? 4. What is $\omega$ usually called? integrand?

Comment: 1. An interval is a $1$-manifold. (A general $1$-manifold could be disconnected, or not embedded in $\mathbf{R}$, or homeomorphic to a circle, etc.) 2. A diffeomorphism here would be a smooth bijection with non-vanishing derivative. 3. A $0$-form is just a function (usually by definition). 4. Yes, "integrand" would be a reasonable name; depending on your point of view, in elementary calculus you integrate $1$-forms $f(x)\, dx$, not functions $f$.