# The inegral $\int_1^2 2x \sqrt{x^2 + 1}\; dx$ using differential forms

Tags: calculus, differential-forms

I am trying to learn about differential forms. I think I understand what they are and the basic idea of integrals. But I wanted to make sure that I understand the process of integration by substitution using differential forms.

**My basic question is how to do integration by substitution using differential forms**.

I have tried the following example:

Say I want to calculate
$$
\int_1^2 x\sqrt{x^2 +1}\; dx.
$$
If I can recognize $f(x) = 2x\sqrt{x^2 + 1}\; dx$ as the differential of a $0$-form, then I can use Stoke's theorem. So I define the $0$-form $u = x^2 + 1$ and find the differential $du = 2x\;dx$. That is $\frac{1}{2}u = x\; dx$. So these two $0$-forms are the same as $1$-forms. Then as $1$-forms

$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{u}\;du = x\sqrt{x^2+ 1}\;dx$$

Then I am integrating using Stoke's Theorem
$$\begin{align}
\int_1^2 x\sqrt{x^2 +1}\; dx &= \int_1^2 \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{u}\;du = ...
\end{align}
$$
Is that saying it the right way? Do I have to change the limits on the integral? How does that work?

Comment: You need to be more careful with basic calculus. The $u$ you have does not satisfy the equation $du = 2x\sqrt{x^2 + 1} \ dx$.

Comment: @SimonS: Ok, Ah... then I am not quite sure how to write it.

Comment: $ u = \frac{2}{3}(x^2 + 1)^{3/2}$

Comment: Basic calculus tells me $u=x^2+1$ implies $du=2xdx$

Comment: @JohnDoe In the theory of differential forms, the idea of "substitution" [corresponds to the notion of "pullbacks"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304737/what-is-a-pullback-in-simple-calculus-context/1304788#1304788). Since you've only been studying differential forms for like $1$ day, maybe it's a little early to be considering this. First just work through that pdf. When you're done with that, pick up a longer book or set of lecture notes on differential forms.

Comment: @Bye_World: Ok, I wanted to understand as much as I can this weekend. Come Monday, my mind will be elsewhere :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the integral $$\int_1^2 x\sqrt{x^2 +1}\; dx$$

We can consider this to be the integral of the one-form $f(x)\ dx = x\sqrt{x^2 +1}\; dx$ on the "$1$-dimensional manifold with boundary" $M=[1,2]$.

The way that "pulling back" and "pushing forward" works in differential forms is summed up in this formula: $$\int_{N} \omega = \int_{M} \phi^{*}\omega$$

where we define the *pullback of $\omega$ by $\phi$* as $\phi^* \omega := \omega \circ \phi$ and $M$ and $N:=\phi(M)$ are the regions of integration.

Sometimes the way to simplify our integrand will be to recognize it as the composition of a differential form with another function (like in this example).  That's called a "pushfoward" and it's described by starting from the RHS of the above formula and finding the *simpler* LHS.  Other times we'll want to compose our differential form with another function to simplify it.  That's called a "pullback" and it's described by starting from the LHS of the above formula and finding the *simpler* RHS.

Here we'd like to use a pushforward.  So essentially we just need to find a bijective, differentiable function $\phi: M \to N$ that we can use to *simplify* the integrand.  You make a good suggestion in your post with $u=x^2+1$ (notice that this is bijective on $[1,2]$).  Let's let $\phi(x) = x^2+1$.  Then we can see that if $\omega$ is our *simplified* differential form, then $$f(x)\ dx = \phi^* \omega = \omega\circ \phi = g(\phi(x))\phi'(x)\ dx = x\sqrt{x^2+1}\ dx$$

Then, knowing that $d\phi = \phi'(x)\ dx = 2x\ dx$, we see that clearly $g(t)\ dt = \frac 12\sqrt{t}\ dt = \omega$ (do you see where the $\frac 12$ comes from?).

So then $$\int_1^2 x\sqrt{x^2+1}\ dx = \int_{M} \phi^*\omega = \int_{\phi(M)} \omega = \int_{\phi(1)}^{\phi(2)} \frac 12\sqrt{t}\ dt = \int_1^5 \frac 12\sqrt{t}\ dt$$

This last integral is much easier to solve (using the fundamental theorem of calculus; AKA Stokes' theorem).

Notice that this is exactly the same procedure as you would use with regular scalar calculus (only you call it $u$ instead of $\phi$).  In a sense, scalar calculus is already "complete".  By that I mean that all of those cool generalizations we've got for it, like integration of differential forms and tensors, don't really add anything to the $1$-dimensional case.  To really see where differential forms are useful you'll have to wait until you start studying more interesting manifolds in differential geometry.

---

For an example of a pullback, consider the integral $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx$$

I claim that composing the differential form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx$ with the function $\phi(\theta) = \sin(\theta)$ will make this integral easier to evaluate.  Give it a try.

Hint: when starting from the LHS of the formula I give above you'll find that $M=\phi^{-1}(N)$ -- this is why $\phi$ has to be a bijective function.  Is $\sin(\theta)$ a bijective function on $N=[0,1]$?

Comment: You should have $g(\phi(x)) \phi'(x) dx = \mathbf{2} x \sqrt{x^2+1} dx$.

Comment: Why should I do that?  There's no $2$ in OP's question.

Comment: Sorry, I also said it wrong: my point is that in that line it is not very clear where the $\frac{1}{2}$ comes in.

Comment: I added in the derivative of $\phi$ to that line to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: I think it's better that way. I do think OP can piece it together (indeed as you said earlier it is exactly identical to what we usually write in calculus; only the notation is different). But I also think it is helpful for OP to see an example written out top to bottom in form notation.

Answer (score 1):

Your differentiation of $u$ is incorrect, leading to incorrect substitution.

Also your limits do need to change when you change from $x$ to $u$. This does have the advantage that you don't need to substitute back in $x$, you can just apply the limits to $u$.

Let $u=x^2+1$, hence $du=2xdx$.

When $x=1$, $u=2$.

When $x=2$, $u=5$.

$$\begin{align}
\int_1^2 x\sqrt{x^2 +1}\; dx &= \int_2^5 \frac{1}{2}u^{\frac{1}{2}}du = \frac{1}{3}( u^{\frac{3}{2}}(2) - u^{\frac{3}{2}}(1)) =\frac{1}{3}(5\sqrt{5}-2\sqrt{2})..
\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you use the language of differential forms?